# Can I use Polymorphism in switching types for KeyCode

Tags: oop, if-statement, polymorphism, keycode

I read about Anti-If campaign. Most of them said use Polymorphism to replace conditional.

So, should I always use Polymorphism when switching types like KeyCode in KeyEventArgs in a KeyDown event(in WinForms)?

I always use this kind of code.

```
   If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
      'Do F1 things
   ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F2 Then
      'Do F2 things
   End If
```

Is it bad? If yes (Oh another IF), Can you give me sample of a polymorphic approach..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the language you're using and your specific use case, one approach you could create a map, where the keys are your keyCodes and the values are function pointers, with the actions that need to be executed.

Even better, you could do one more level of indirection, where your values are some kind of Action objects, that each knows how to be executed. This way, you can reuse code to trigger the same kind of functionality in many different contexts.

Comment: I understand. But the initial mapping of each keycode to an action object would require conditional right? Case Keys.F1 : Map.Add(Keys.F1, ActionObject). I'm figuring out if there is a way I cannot do conditionals

Comment: You don't need conditionals. When you initialize your map, assuming you have a function called Construct(), that is called when your app / window/whatever starts:

Construct()
{
   Map.Add(Keys.F1, new HelpAction());
   Map.Add(Keys.Q, new QuitAction());
}

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm bounded to our table which is where i'm getting the function name like "QuitAction" together with its permission. So in the constructor I need to query first the table then do the mapping.